# How to make process.standardinput bitmap stream work in tesseract?

Tags: c#, process, bitmap, tesseract, stdin

I'm trying to capture part of a desktop image then run it with tesseract.exe without having to write a captured image on to the disk as a file.
However, the following code gives me an error or a process will not end. Help please?

```
Bitmap bmp=capture_and_crop();
       using (Process process = new Process())
                        {                
                            process.StartInfo.FileName = ts5path+"tesseract.exe";
                        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "stdin" + " stdout -l " + language + " --psm " + PSM_setting + " -c preserve_interword_spaces=1";
                                                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        
                            process.Start();
                            
                            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);//line1. I get error here : standardIn has not been redirected, when I move these 2 lines above process.Start().
                            bmp.Save(writer.BaseStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);//line2.
    //If these lines stay here there will be no redirection exception but this process will never end...
        
                            StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
                            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            addtr1.str = output;
                        
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        }
```

Comment: You issue is detecting when the process finishes.  WaitForExit will not become true until the process closes.  Does the application return a result?   ReadToEnd has to be in a loop because it returns immediately.  You are reading a stream and ReadToEnd reads to the end of a stream. I the application  ends in a return you can use ReadLine() instead.  If the application stays open then WaitForExit should be eliminated then code should work unless the application doesn't have a return on the StandardOutput (application may have a '\0' instead of a return).

Comment: If I don't use stdIn then this code works perfectly. However, that means that I have to save the image file to the disk then use it instead of stdin. The question is how do I make it work with stdin.

Comment: When you save to file windows closes the stream so everything work fine.  You are writing the data correctly and then hanging because you are not detecting when the app completes.

Comment: I removed WaitForExit and I changed ReadToEnd to ReadLine() but the program still hangs. Then when I move BinaryWriter writer part to the above process.start then it causes 'System.InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected.'

Comment: You have to look at the response and see the end character(s).  It may be a null or instead of a windows return '\n' it may be just a '\r'.

Comment: string output = reader.ReadLine(); I put a messagebox to check where it hangs and then it stops in reader.readline(). It seems tesseract 5.0 can't read stdin. Is there better way to copy bitmap as byte data to stdin?

Comment: BinaryWriter is the correct method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);                                        
                    bmp.Save(writer.BaseStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();
```

Many thanks to jdweng.         process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close(); was needed right after bitmap was written into the stdin basestream to close the stream so ReadtoEnd can close and the program can move on after.